# train_test_split not splitting data

Tags: python, scikit-learn, train-test-split

There is a dataframe that consists of 14 columns in total, the last column is the target label with integer values = 0 or 1.

I have defined:

1. `X = df.iloc[:,1:13]` ---- this consists of the feature values
2. `y = df.iloc[:,-1]` ------ this consists of the corresponding labels

Both have the same length as desired, `X` is the dataframe that consists of 13 columns, shape (159880, 13), `y` is an array type with shape(159880,)

But when I perform `train_test_split()` on `X`,`y`- the function is not working properly.

Below is the straightforward code:

```py
X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state = 0)
```

After this split, both `X_train` and `X_test` have shape (119910,13). `y_train` is having shape (39970,13) and `y_test` is having shape (39970,)

This is weird, even after defining `test_size` parameter, the results stay the same.

Please advise, what could have been going wrong.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from adspy_shared_utilities import plot_feature_importances
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

def model():
    
    df = pd.read_csv('train.csv', encoding = 'ISO-8859-1')
    df = df[np.isfinite(df['compliance'])]
    df = df.fillna(0)
    df['compliance'] = df['compliance'].astype('int')
    df = df.drop(['grafitti_status', 'violation_street_number','violation_street_name','violator_name',
                  'inspector_name','mailing_address_str_name','mailing_address_str_number','payment_status',
                  'compliance_detail', 'collection_status','payment_date','disposition','violation_description',
                  'hearing_date','ticket_issued_date','mailing_address_str_name','city','state','country',
                  'violation_street_name','agency_name','violation_code'], axis=1)
    df['violation_zip_code'] = df['violation_zip_code'].replace(['ONTARIO, Canada',', Australia','M3C1L-7000'], 0)
    df['zip_code'] = df['zip_code'].replace(['ONTARIO, Canada',', Australia','M3C1L-7000'], 0)
    df['non_us_str_code'] = df['non_us_str_code'].replace(['ONTARIO, Canada',', Australia','M3C1L-7000'], 0)
    df['violation_zip_code'] = pd.to_numeric(df['violation_zip_code'], errors='coerce')
    df['zip_code'] = pd.to_numeric(df['zip_code'], errors='coerce')
    df['non_us_str_code'] = pd.to_numeric(df['non_us_str_code'], errors='coerce')
    #df.violation_zip_code = df.violation_zip_code.replace('-','', inplace=True)
    df['violation_zip_code'] = np.nan_to_num(df['violation_zip_code'])
    df['zip_code'] = np.nan_to_num(df['zip_code'])
    df['non_us_str_code'] = np.nan_to_num(df['non_us_str_code'])
    X = df.iloc[:,0:13]
    y = df.iloc[:,-1]
    X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state = 0)    
    print(y_train.shape)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have mixed up the results of train_test_split, it should be

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2,random_state=0)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if args.mode == "train":

    # Load Data
    data, labels = load_dataset('C:/Users/PC/Desktop/train/k')

    # Train ML models
    knn(data, labels,'C:/Users/PC/Desktop/train/knn.pkl' )
```

Comment: Your answer is unclear. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62238326/edit) to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked by OP. You can find more information on how to write [good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) in the help center.